# c++ Do Local variables, with reserved memory, need to be freed?

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I've a simply question. 
I have been looking for the answer but I might not found the correct tags or words to find the solution...

The question is, as the title says: Do local variables (which have reserved memory) need to be freed? I meant, for example, if I've got the following function:

```
myClass* myFunction(){
myClass* A = new myClass;
return A;
}
```

In case of "yes", where Should I call "delete"? both before and after "return" are nonsense...

Am I right?

Comment: There is no answer because the question makes no sense in C++, unless `myClass` has a constructor that takes a `myClass` pointer.

Comment: I bet you come from Java or C#!

Comment: I came from Java... That why I'm not used to those troubles... Sorry If the question seems stupid

Comment: Try to write C++ without using new to begin with.

Comment: Ok, I think that now I understand better the trouble. Thank for your help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use `new` unless you need to.

This avoids `new`, and so doesn't need deleting

```
myClass myFunction(){
    myClass A;
    return A;
}
```

If you think you need pointers, consider using smart pointers.

If you want the excitement of raw pointers, this function returns a raw pointer to the caller, and they must delete it when they are done.

```
myClass * myFunction(){
    myClass * A = new myClass;
    return A;
}

myClass * thing = myFunction();
//stuff, that might throw an exception, so watch it
// smart pointers FTW
delete thing;
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your type is defined something like this:

```
class myClass { /* ... */ };
```

Your example is not proper C++ (unless you have a `myClass*` conversion constructor, which you probably don't).

You do not have to `new` an object that sits on automatic memory:

```
myClass myFunction(){
  myClass a;
  return a;
}
```

When newing an object on *dynamic memory*, you can then put it into a pointer variable in automatic memory:

```
myClass* myFunction(){
  myClass* a = new myClass;
  return a;
}
```

Here, `a` might leak, if it isn't freed by the caller.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, unless you're doing some interesting operator overloading, you mean to assign new myClass to a pointer and return the pointer

```
myClass *myFunction(){
  myClass *A = new myClass;
 return A;
}
```

If that is the case, then yes, you will have to delete it at some point. It will be up to the caller of this function to keep the pointer and delete it when appropriate.

Alternatively you can use smartpointers.

Answer (score 1):

Use shared_ptr instead of raw pointers.

```
std::shared_ptr<myClass> myFunction()
{
    std::shared_ptr<myClass> A = std::make_shared<myClass>(constructor parameters, if any);
    return A;
}

void f()
{
    std::shared_ptr<myClass> A = myFunction();
}
```

This will emulate Java-style garbage collection.